# Function that concatenates a string and a integer converts to float before converting to string

Tags: python, pandas

I've written an if-else function that, based on the number of the quarter, concatenates a string (i.e. '1/1/') with an integer converted to a string (i.e. str(2017)). I have three data frames I want to use this on. Two of the data frames produce the expected result (i.e. '1/1/2017'). The last data frame produces the following '1/1/2017.0'which makes it not convert to a datetime.

I'm at a loss because based on the dtypes, all three dataframes list both quarter and year as int64, and all three dataframes originally come from the same csv.

My first guess was that I had converted my years to a float at some point when I was preparing the last data frame. I tried to ensure that the year column was an integer with .astype(). The year column is listed under .dtypes as an int64 before and after the function is applied.

Data Frame

```
from pandas import DataFrame

Data = {'quarter': [1,2,3,4],
         'year': [2017,2017,2017,2017]}
df = DataFrame(Data, columns = ['quarter', 'year'])
```

This is the function I am using

```
def f(row):
    if row['quarter'] == 1:
        val = '1/1/' + str(row['year'])
    elif row['quarter'] == 2:
        val = '4/1/' + str(row['year'])
    elif row['quarter'] == 3:
        val = '7/1/' + str(row['year'])
    else:
        val = '10/1/' + str(row['year'])
    return val
```

My expected result would be '1/1/2017', '4/1/2017', '7/1/2017', '10/1/2017'

I don't receive any error messages or warnings.

Comment: It works for me. This `for _, row in df.iterrows(): print(f(row))` prints `1/1/2017`, `4/1/2017`, `7/1/2017`, and `10/1/2017` (each in a separate line).

Comment: My main problem is that it works exactly as intended on two other dataframes. I can't make any sense of why the exact same conditions would produce a different result on the third

Comment: Then you should probably post the third dataframe in your question, the one that doesn't work.

Comment: Are there null/NaN rows in the year column in the df that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your code doesn't work with the third dataset, but you could use pandas' functions instead of writing your own. It might resolve your problem.

```py
>>> df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(
...     df['year'].astype(str).str.cat(df['quarter'].astype(str), sep='Q'))
>>> df
   quarter  year       date
0        1  2017 2017-01-01
1        2  2017 2017-04-01
2        3  2017 2017-07-01
3        4  2017 2017-10-01
```

---

You could change date format like:

```py
>>> df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
0    01/01/2017
1    04/01/2017
2    07/01/2017
3    10/01/2017
Name: date, dtype: object
```